# JSF 2.2.10, Tomcat 8, JAAS login fail

Tags: jsf-2, jaas, tomcat8

I'm trying to implement a JSF2 JAAS login on Tomcat 8 using a JDBC realm.  I've configured the tables on my database for the JDBC login using this resource: [Tomcat man page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm)
My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Views only available when logged in as ADMIN</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Views only available when logged in as USER</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginFail.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error-pages/forbidden.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error-pages/notFound.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

My JSF login page:

```
<h:form>
        <p:panel rendered="#{!loginManager.userLoggedIn}">
            You are not logged in.
            <p/>
            <p:inputText id="userName" placeholder="your assigned user name" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Please enter your user name"/>
            <p/>
            <p:inputText type="password" placeholder="your password" id="password" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Please enter your password"/>
            <p/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{loginManager.login()}" id="login" value="Enter"/>
        </p:panel>
        <p:panel rendered="#{loginManager.userLoggedIn}">
            Hello, <strong>#{loginManager.user}</strong>.
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```

The LoginManager:

```
    public void login() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext externalContext = externalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
    try {
        request.login(username, password);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        String loginErrorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
        facesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(loginErrorMessage));
    }
}
```

The error occurs here:

```
request.login(username, password);
```

The error is "login failed"

How can I get the login to succeed?

Comment: Where's your `<realm-name>`? Did you define a realm?

Comment: What I did forget was to implement the actual JAAS login module lol.  Thanks for the assistance though